# Need single HTML structure as attached screenshot for desktop and mobile, without duplicating the elements. Is it possible with flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Need the HTML & CSS code if this can be implemented with flex box layout.

[attached layout for desktop(left) & mobile (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btowC.jpg)

Comment: hope you can get some idea using this: https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

Comment: is should be possible with flex order: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Answer (score 0):

Using `display:flex` you can set the order of elements and change the order on mobile.

```css
.fruit-holder {
  display: flex;
}

.banana {
  order: 3;
}

.apple {
  order: 2;
}

.orange {
  order: 1;
}

/* below is code for mobile */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.banana {
  order: 1;
}

.apple {
  order: 2;
}

.orange {
  order: 3;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="fruit-holder">
  <div class="banana">Banana</div>
  <div class="apple">Apple</div>
  <div class="orange">Orange</div>
</div>
```